# Three js: How to normalize a mesh generated by vertices

Tags: three.js, linear-algebra

I'm somewhat new to Three js, and my linear algebra days were back in the 90s so I don't recall much about quarternions.  My issue is I have 8 vertices for a cube that I can use to create a custom geometry mesh from, but it doesn't set the position / rotation / scale info for its world matrix.  Therefor it can not be used cleanly by other three js modules like controls.  I can look up the math and calculate what position / scale / rotation (rotation gets a bit hairy with some fun acos stuff) should be and create a standard boxgeometry from that.  But it seems like there should be some way to do it via three js objects if I can generate the proper matrix to apply to it.  The quarternion setFromUnitVectors looked interesting, but I'd still have to do some work to generate the vectors.  Any ideas would be appreciated thanks

---

Edit: :) So let me try and simplify.  I have 8 vertices, I want to create a box geometry.  But box geometry doesn't take vertices.  It takes width, height, depth (relatively easy to calculate) and then you set the position/scale/rotation.  So here's my code thus far:

```
  5____4
1/___0/|
| 6__|_7
2/___3/

const box = new Box3();
box.setFromPoints(points);

const width = points[1].distanceTo(points[0]);
const height = points[3].distanceTo(points[0]);
const depth = points[4].distanceTo(points[0]);

const geometry = new BoxGeometry(width, height, depth);
mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);

const center = box.getCenter(new Vector3());
const normalizedCorner = points[0].clone().sub(center);
const quarterian = new Quaternion();
quarterian.setFromUnitVectors(geometry.vertices[0], normalizedCorner);
mesh.setRotationFromQuaternion(quarterian);
mesh.position.copy(center);
```

The problem being my rotation element is wrong (besides my vectors not being unit vectors).  I'm apparently not getting the correct quarternion to rotate my mesh correctly.

---

Edit:  From WestLangley's suggestion, I'm creating a rotation matrix. However, while it rotates in the correct plane, the angle is off.  Here's what I have added:

```
const matrix = new Matrix4();
const widthVector = new Vector3().subVectors(points[6], points[7]).normalize();
const heightVector = new Vector3().subVectors(points[6], points[5]).normalize();
const depthVector = new Vector3().subVectors(points[6], points[2]).normalize();

matrix.set(
  widthVector.x, heightVector.x, depthVector.x, 0,
  widthVector.y, heightVector.y, depthVector.y, 0,
  widthVector.z, heightVector.z, depthVector.z, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1,
);
mesh.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: I read this two times and did not understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear @pailhead.   Let me know if this makes sense

Comment: console log `geometry.vertices[0].length()` and `normalizedCorner.length()` in order for the quaternion method to work i think these two need to be unit. Do you want **to visualize the bounding box of a number of points, by using the `BoxGeometry`**?

Comment: I think you're confused by some concepts here. If you have 8 vertices (0-7) that are already corners of boxes, why are you using the `Box3` class at all?

Comment: @JimSosa Is the box rotated -- that is, not axis-aligned? If so, you need to use `mesh.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix( matrix4 )`. You populate the upper-left 3x3 of `matrix4` with three, column, unit vectors 6->7, 6->5, and 6->2. That should set the quaternion so your mesh is oriented according to your points -- as long as the three vectors are in fact orthogonal (important!) and unit-length (important!).

Comment: As @WestLangley said, the big issue here is rotation.  Without rotation this is rather simple.  I'm still a little unclear on how I'd build a rotation matrix.   You mention upper left.  Do you mean I only need that part of the matrix `v(6, 7) v(6,5) v(6, 2) 0` and the rest are zeros? or 1s in the diagonal?  All vectors should be orthogonal as this will be a standard cube just rotated.

Comment: You need to set _column_ unit vectors -- not row vectors. Try the transpose of what you have specified.

Comment: I did try that @WestLangley.  You mean like `widthVector.x, heightVector.x, depthVector.x, 0` in the top row of the matrix.  That didn't work either

Comment: No, in the first column.

Comment: If it is not working, then maybe you can provide a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/s3rjfcc3/

Comment: Your vectors are backwards. `new Vector3().subVectors( points[ 7 ], points[ 6 ] ).normalize();`

Comment: :) . I was thinking it was distance and order didn't matter.  That did the trick.  Want to make an answer so I can close this out?  Thanks also for you post some 6 years ago.  I need to read up on Math, so I'm assuming the concepts haven't changed much

Comment: @JimSosa When there are multiple users commenting to a post, you have to direct your question with '@username', otherwise the user is never notified of your comment...

Comment: Ooops.  @WestLangley I meant to include your name.  If you want to make an answer I will switch the flag.  Thanks again

Comment: @JimSosa Oh, that's not necessary. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per WestLangley's comments I wasn't creating my matrix correctly.  The correct matrix looks like:

```
const matrix = new Matrix4();
const widthVector = new Vector3().subVectors(points[7], points[6]).normalize();
const heightVector = new Vector3().subVectors(points[5], points[6]).normalize();
const depthVector = new Vector3().subVectors(points[2], points[6]).normalize();

matrix.set(
  widthVector.x, heightVector.x, depthVector.x, 0,
  widthVector.y, heightVector.y, depthVector.y, 0,
  widthVector.z, heightVector.z, depthVector.z, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1,
);
mesh.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(matrix);
```